# Excel counting files in a folder with sub-folders wrong

Tags: excel, vba

It works right with single folders but if the treee level is higher than 2, the error increases with the length of he tree.

I am trying to get quantity of *xl* in a folde including subfolders in order to create an array.

(I will use open all files within another sub and create a report)

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Countfiles(FF As Scripting.Folder)
        Dim F As Scripting.file
        Dim SubF As Scripting.Folder
        Dim k As Integer

        For Each F In FF.Files
                If F.Path Like "*.xl*" Then
                        k = k + 1
                        Debug.Print r_tot + k
                Else
                End If
        Next

        For Each SubF In FF.Subfolders
                r_tot = r_tot + k
                Countfiles SubF
        Next SubF

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using recursive function, just loop through the folder/sub-folders and count files like it's shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753701/count-files-in-specific-folder-and-display-the-number-into-1-cel Rgds,

Comment: @alexbell how will that work given the question clearly wants to go furthr than one level of subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet to get files count (of Excel types .xls) in a single folder. Apply it to all folders of interest and add the count to accumulator var.

```
Function FilesCount(FolderPath)
    Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer

    path = FolderPath & "\*.xls"
    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
       Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    FilesCount=count
End Sub
```

Hope this will help. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration for the loop has it's own instance of `k`, you are not returning it's value to the calling routine

You can add the count as a parameter to the `Sub`

```
Private Sub Countfiles(FF As Scripting.Folder, ByRef count As Long)
    Dim f As Scripting.file
    Dim SubF As Scripting.Folder

    For Each f In FF.Files
        If f.Path Like "*.xl*" Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each SubF In FF.Subfolders
        Countfiles SubF, count
    Next SubF   

End Sub
```

or convert it to a `Function`

```
Function fCountfiles(FF As Scripting.Folder) As Long
    Dim count As Long       
    Dim f As Scripting.file
    Dim SubF As Scripting.Folder

    For Each f In FF.Files
        If f.Path Like "*.xl*" Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next

    For Each SubF In FF.Subfolders
        count = count + fCountfiles(SubF)
    Next SubF
    fCountfiles = count
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `PowerShell` via `VBA` - a single line is enough to count files and folders recursively (or to dump a complete list of the same).

The code below is a great improvement on recursive looping using *FSO* or *DIR*, but frustratingly long compared to the simplicity of using `PowerShell` directly which to look from a folder `C:\temp` is just:

`Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem c:\temp -recurse -include *.xls* | Measure-Object | export-csv C:\temp\filename.csv`

- change `strFolder` to set the folder of interest for the count of files and folders

*code*

```
Sub BYpass()
Dim strFolder As String
Dim StrIn As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim X1
Dim X2
strFolder = "c:\temp"
StrIn = "C:\temp\filename.csv"
'export file count
X1 = Shell("powershell.exe Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem " & strFolder & " -recurse -include *.xls* | Measure-Object | export-csv " & StrIn & ")", 1)
'export detail of all files
X2 = Shell("powershell.exe Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem " & strFolder & " -recurse -include *.xls* | export-csv " & StrIn & ")", 1)
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(StrIn)
End Sub
```