# count how many of files in each folder and subfolder then display separately

Tags: excel, vba

I have obtained the filename and corresponding folder in column a and b.

How Can I count the number of files in each folder and subfolder?

these are the references:

[count files in specific folder and display the number into 1 cel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753701/count-files-in-specific-folder-and-display-the-number-into-1-cel)

http://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-find-and-list-all-files-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories/

I have done the following so far

```
Private Sub SelectFolder_Click()
Call GetAllFolders(x, strPath, objFso, intCountRows)
Call count
End Sub
```

The following is the counting part

```
Sub count()
Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
Dim Filename As String
Dim strPath As String

FolderPath = "D:\Users\Desktop\test"

Filename = Dir("")

Do While Filename <> ""
   count = count + 1
   Filename = Dir()
Loop

Range("C3").Value = count
'MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"
End Sub
```

How Can I count the number of files in each folder and subfolder? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GetFileCount will count all the files in a directory and the directory's sub-directories.

`Range("C3").Value = getFileCount("D:\Users\Desktop\test")`

```
Function getFileCount(localRoot, Optional fld, Optional count As Long) As Long
    Dim fso, f, baseFolder, subFolder, ftpFile, i

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

    If IsMissing(fld) Then
        Set baseFolder = fso.GetFolder(localRoot)
    Else
        Set baseFolder = fld
    End If

    count = count + baseFolder.Files.count

    For Each subFolder In baseFolder.SubFolders
        getFileCount localRoot, subFolder, count
    Next

    getFileCount = count
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's works for counting total number of files in folder.
But what if I want to display the number of files in folder and subfolder seperately

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: Do you know how to display the number separately?

Comment: Would you want it in 1 cell?  Or would you want the Folders to branch off into adjacent cells?

Comment: I would like to show the number in different cells according to folders' directory.

Comment: This is confusing...lol.  I'll get back to you tomorrow night.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help. I found this code:

```
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'DESCRIPTION: This macro counts the files in a folder and retuns the result in a msgbox
'INPUT: Pass the procedure a string with your directory path and an optional
' file extension with the * wildcard
'EXAMPLES: Call CountFilesInFolder("C:\Users\Ryan\")
' Call CountFilesInFolder("C:\Users\Ryan\", "*txt")

Private Sub CountFilesInFolder(strDir As String, Optional strType As String)

Dim file As Variant, i As Integer
If Right(strDir, 1) <> "\" Then strDir = strDir & "\"
file = Dir(strDir & strType)
While (file <> "")
    i = i + 1
    file = Dir
Wend
MsgBox "Num of files are " & i

End Sub
```

---

Then I modified a little:

```
Sub CountFiles()

Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("What is the file path?")
Range("A1").Value = myValue '(Put the given value into A1)
myValue = InputBox("What is the second file path?")
Range("A2").Value = myValue '(Put the given value into A2)

Call CountFilesInFolder(Range("A1").Value)
Call CountFilesInFolder(Range("A2").Value)

End Sub
```